# How to write JUnit testcase for unknown output

Tags: java, junit

How to write a junit testcase  which contains database transaction and we are not sure about the output .. let say getting count from a query or an ID after querying based on several conditions  . Is this a valid comparison if we are checking for count > 0 or Id > 0 ?

Comment: Initialize your database with a fixture or mock it.

Comment: Yep, in general, don't have a unit test that relies on a *real* database that could be in an unknown state.

Answer (score 3):

The whole concept of testing relies on matching the actual state against the expectations.
This implies that the expectations are well defined and known in advance.

I guess you're trying to check the transaction, in this case you should simulate the data.

You can start with a predefined mock data (always the same data), so that the code will query the existing data and you'll know exactly what is expected to be returned.

Alternatively you can create a random data in the beginning of the test and build the test flow so that you always know what will be the result of the query.

Although these approaches are nearly the same, the second one comes handy when its required to run tests in parallel on the same schema/database.
On the other hand, maybe the coding of such a test will be somewhat trickier.

Hope this helps